# How can i build this json in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have to build the below type of json,

```
{
  "MyRquest": {
    "-xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "serialNo": "70813BACH194294",
    "orderslist": {
      "orderid": [
        "5026538",
        "5026539"
      ],
      "ordersource": [
        "ONLINE",
        "STORE"
      ],
      "transactiondtm": [
        "2013-10-08",
        "2013-10-09"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Orderid 5026538 has the order source online and its transaction date is 2013-10-08. Similarly i might have 5 orders and their corresponding order sources and transcation time.

How can i dynamically create this json in javascript?

Comment: Why would you want to? That structure just asks for errors... Parallel arrays are usually a good source of bugs; use a single array of objects instead.

Comment: Do you really mean JSON? You want to create a string? JSON is a textual notation for data exchange.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ya string in json format..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you create the object:

```
var req = {
  "MyRquest": {
    "-xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "serialNo": "70813BACH194294",
    "orderslist": {
      "orderid":        [],
      "ordersource":    [],
      "transactiondtm": []
    }
  }
};
```

*(Really `MyRquest`?)*

Then you add to it as necessary; parallel arrays are a fragile structure, probably best to have a function to do it:

```
function addOrder(req, orderId, orderSource, transactiondtm) {
    req.MyRquest.orderslist.orderid.push(orderId);
    req.MyRquest.orderslist.ordersource.push(orderSource);
    req.MyRquest.orderslist.transactiondtm.push(transactiondtm);
}
```

Then, if you really want JSON, you serialize it:

```
var str = JSON.stringify(req);
```